# Превратите объекты со ссылками в JSON

Tags: javascript

Помогите превратить `team` в JSON, чтобы он заработал. `leader` и `soldier` должны ссылаться друг на друга.

```
var leader = {
  name: "Василий Иванович"
};

var soldier = {
  name: "Петька"
};

leader.soldier = soldier;
soldier.leader = leader;

var team = [leader, soldier];
```

Comment: что вы понимаете под JSON, и под _leader и soldier должны ссылаться друг на друга_?

Comment: Превратить объект team  в JSON и чтобы  leader и soldier ссылались друг на друга

Comment: вы скопировали строку из вопроса, но так и не объяснили что вы под этим имеете ввиду

Comment: вот задача, она не получается...

Comment: Превратите объект team из примера ниже в JSON:var leader = {
  name: "Василий Иванович"
};

var soldier = {
  name: "Петька"
};

// эти объекты ссылаются друг на друга!
leader.soldier = soldier;
soldier.leader = leader;

var team = [leader, soldier];

Comment: во, вот это как раз в вопрос надо вставить

Comment: В общем случае это невозможно из-за циклической ссылки, но если будет пример ожидаемой строки - вполне можно сделать решение для конкретного случая

Comment: то есть это невозможно???

Comment: в ответе есть такой вариант решения, но я не знаю как его написать....team.toJSON = function() {
  /* свой код, который может создавать копию объекта без круговых ссылок и передавать управление JSON.stringify */
}

Comment: а где вы эту задачу нашли?:)

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/json#tasks  хочу понять, но мозгов не хватает

Comment: @aleksei, вам же черным по белому написали в решении, что JSON не поддерживает циклические ссылки. Все, что может придумать автор это "руководства" либо кто-то еще сводится к костылям разной степени кривости. На практике, передавать данные с циклическими ссылками - плохая идея (даже без учета проблем с JSON).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В качестве одного из решений сериализации, можно воспользоваться параметром `replacer` в функции [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) и для нужных полей возвращать не зацикленный объект, а что-то другое, например:

```js
var leader = {
  name: "Василий Иванович"
};

var soldier = {
  name: "Петька"
};

// эти объекты ссылаются друг на друга!
leader.soldier = soldier;
soldier.leader = leader;

var team = [leader, soldier];


document.write(JSON.stringify(team, function(k, v) {
  if (k == "leader") return {
    name: v.name
  };
  if (k == "soldier") return {
    name: v.name
  };
  return v;
}))
```

Answer (score 2):

Сложить все объекты в массив, заменив значения из полей индексами в этом массиве.

```js
function stringify(obj) {
  var map = new Map(), objs = [obj];
  
  for (var q=0; q<objs.length; ++q) {
    if (typeof objs[q] === 'object') {
      obj = objs[q] = Array.isArray(objs[q]) ? [].concat(objs[q]) : Object.assign({}, objs[q]);

      for (var key in obj) {
        var i = map.get(obj[key]);

        if (i == null) {
          map.set(obj[key], i=objs.length);
          objs.push(obj[key]);
        }

        obj[key] = i;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return JSON.stringify(objs);
}

~function () {
  var leader = {
    name: "Василий Иванович"
  };

  var soldier = {
    name: "Петька"
  };

  leader.soldier = soldier;
  soldier.leader = leader;

  var team = [leader, soldier];

  document.body.textContent = stringify(team);
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

А вот мой вариант:

```js
let man = {
"name":"Pasha",
"age":20,
};
man.friend = man;

let arr=[];

function removeCircular(obj){
//проходим циклом по всем ключам
  for (key in obj){
    let testObj = obj[key]
//каждый ключ пробуем сериализовать
    try{
      JSON.stringify(testObj)
//если не получается, добавляем этот ключ (а по сути объект) в массив
    }catch(err){
      arr.push(testObj);
 //проверяем ключ, на идентичность (объекты для сравнения лежат в массиве)
      let d = checkInstanse(testObj);
// если идентичных объектов найдено не было - ищем идентичности внутри этого ключа(объекта)
      if(!d){ 
        removeCircular(testObj)
      } else{
     delete obj[key]
     obj[key] = Object.assign({}, d)
    
     }
    } 
   }
  }

function checkInstanse(obj){
  let returnObj;
  for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if (Object.is(arr[i], obj)){
    returnObj = obj;
   }
  }
  return returnObj
}

removeCircular(man);
console.log(JSON.stringify(man));
```