# JS Как преобразовать двумерный ассоциативный массив в json?

Tags: javascript, json

У меня есть ассоциативный массив (объект) `selectedData`
При попытках преобразовать его в JSON вот так:

```
myJson = JSON.stringify(selectedData[0]);
```

или

```
myJson = JSON.stringify(selectedData[1]);
```

и так далее, то все ОК.

Но если мне нужно преобразовать все элементы массива:

```
myJson = JSON.stringify(selectedData);
```

То я получаю ошибку:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Как можно преобразовать двумерный ассоциативный массив в JSON без этой ошибки?

Comment: убрать циклические ссылки и JSON.stringify заработает

Comment: Там что-то такое `arr[0]=arr`, что не имеет ни конца ни края

Answer (score 0):

Если прочитать сообщение об ошибке, то видно, что где-то в массиве есть циклические зависимости. JSON не поддерживает подобные объекты, надо каким-то образом от них избавиться.

Если же требуется сериализовать и десериализовать циклическую структуру в её оригинальном виде, то можно трансформировать сериализуемый объектв массив, содержащий инфомацию по объектам и индексы вместо ссылок. Сама реализация [показана в другом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/525159/178988).

Comment: Я вообще ничего не понял... Неужели настолько простая задача в JS решается так сложно?

Comment: @CoffeeinTime, простая задача решается просто, а у тебя в массиве какая-то муть.