# Почему без key != "" программа перестаёт работать?

Tags: javascript

```js
let room = {
  number: 23
};

let meetup = {
  title: "Conference",
  occupiedBy: [{
    name: "John"
  }, {
    name: "Alice"
  }],
  place: room
};

room.occupiedBy = meetup;
meetup.self = meetup;

alert(JSON.stringify(meetup, function replacer(key, value) {
  return (key != "" && value == meetup) ? undefined : value;
}));
```

А что делает `key != ""` в функции ?

> replacer(key, value)

Почему без него программа перестаёт работать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В документации говорится, что функция `replacer` для самого объекта получает в качестве ключа пустую строку:

> Initially, the replacer function is called with an empty string as key representing the object being stringified. It is then called for each property on the object or array being stringified.
>
> <sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter</sub>

поэтому, если убрать проверку на пустую строку, то для самого сериализуемого объекта `meetup` будет возвращено `undefined` и ничего не сериализуется.

Кстати, вот [один из способов сериализовать циклические объекты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/525159/178988).